# Declaration of Cart::addCartRule($id_cart_rule) should be compatible with CartCore::addCartRule($id_cart_rule, bool $useOrderPrices = false)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In my error_log file I'm getting this error every time and I don't understand why can someone help me?

I'm using prestashop 1.7

> [Thu Oct 13 09:59:12.463274 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 45545:tid 139624745764608] [client 146.59.8.136:33906]
> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Declaration of Cart::addCartRule($id_cart_rule) should be compatible with CartCore::addCartRule($id_cart_rule, bool $useOrderPrices = false) in /var/www/vhosts/wiejski-sklep.pl/httpdocs/override/classes/Cart.php on line 20'

Comment: What don't you understand? The parent signature explicitly states you need to define 2 arguments, you cannot define less arguments for an inherited method

Comment: If you are talking about $userOrderPrices this variable has default FALSE so I dont need to define this argument in function

Comment: Inherited functions must inherit all parameters and return type of the parent, you need both on your function

Comment: What @CanO'Spam said, it's not because it's an optional argument, you can leave it out, because that would alter the signature of the method

Comment: The function signature must be the same.

Comment: Every¹ place where you can use `CartCore`, you must also be able to use `Cart`. For example, if you do `CartCore $test = new Cart();`, and you call `$test->addCartRule($id_cart_rule, true);`, what should happen? (¹ Disclaimer: I'm generalizing... 'every place' except inside CartCore when you're using private properties/methods, and maybe there are other exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the same function signature in your override as in the parent class.

Edit `/override/classes/Cart.php`

and change `addCartRule($id_cart_rule)` to:

`addCartRule($id_cart_rule, bool $useOrderPrices = false)`